# Two identical Perl scripts, but one doesn't work?

Tags: perl

I am working with scripts in Materials Studio, a molecular visualization software. Scripting in this software is done in Perl. I have two versions of a script that multiple text comparison sites have verified are identical, yet one script works fine and the other quits, giving [bogus errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKCzb.png):

[image: screenshot]

Here are the two versions:

1: (This one works)

```
#!perl

# originally part of project:Chi_Flexibles_Sys

#########################################################################################################################################
# README:


# Copyright (C) -------------------,  - All Rights Reserved
# Proprietary Software, All Use Must Be Licensed.
# This software is protected by U.S. Copyright Law and International Treaties. Unauthorized use, duplication, reverse engineering,
# any form of redistribution, or use in part or in whole other than by prior, express, printed and signed license for use is strictly prohibited.
# If you have received this file in error, please notify copyright holder and destroy this and any other copies
# as instructed.

# Copyright (c) 2016,-------------------
# Please donot remove and/or modify this copyright notice from the script without permission from the copyright holder.

#########################################################################################################################################

my $dir='C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Materials Studio Projects\2016-October-nanoreactor\Dimers Files\Documents\Case_5_(D)\Blends\AB\A2 Blends Mixing\Lowest energies'; #put in the current directory, because cwd() doesn't work

my $monomer1 = 'A2';
my $monomer2 = 'B2';

my $outfile1 = "$dir\\$monomer1 $monomer1.txt";
my $outfile2 = "$dir\\$monomer1 $monomer2.txt";
my $outfile3 = "$dir\\$monomer2 $monomer2.txt";

my $forcefield = "Dreiding";
```

2: (This one does not work)

```
#!perl

# originally part of project:Chi_Flexibles_Sys

#########################################################################################################################################
# README:


# Copyright (C) -------------------,  - All Rights Reserved
# Proprietary Software, All Use Must Be Licensed.
# This software is protected by U.S. Copyright Law and International Treaties. Unauthorized use, duplication, reverse engineering,
# any form of redistribution, or use in part or in whole other than by prior, express, printed and signed license for use is strictly prohibited.
# If you have received this file in error, please notify copyright holder and destroy this and any other copies
# as instructed.

# Copyright (c) 2016,-------------------
# Please donot remove and/or modify this copyright notice from the script without permission from the copyright holder.

#########################################################################################################################################

my $dir='C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Materials Studio Projects\2016-October-nanoreactor\Dimers Files\Documents\Case_5_(D)\Blends\AB\A2 Blends Mixing\Lowest energies'; #put in the current directory, because cwd() doesn't work

my $monomer1 = 'A2';
my $monomer2 = 'B2';

my $outfile1 = "$dir\\$monomer1 $monomer1.txt";
my $outfile2 = "$dir\\$monomer1 $monomer2.txt";
my $outfile3 = "$dir\\$monomer2 $monomer2.txt";

my $forcefield = "Dreiding";
```

Can anyone figure out why this wouldn't work? It seems like the two blocks are 100% identical. And the errors I'm getting make no sense - how would there be an error in a comment line?

Comment: so what is different between them?  filename?  are they on the same system?  are you running them as different users?  from different directories?

Comment: @ysth, I'm running them directly one after the other, from the same folder, in the same software, as the same user, etc.

Comment: I can literally click from one scripting window to another, all within Materials Studio. The filenames are different, yes, but other than that, they are identical. Hence my confusion and why I made this post!

Comment: How are you running them? Because the error message says `-e`, which refers to a command-line script, not a file.

Comment: My guess is that there are some non-visible characters like `\0` in one file which mess up the parsing. If you only copy+paste these files on text comparison sites or here these non-text characters will be automatically stripped, i.e. these these files look only the same without being the same. If you expect them to be the same just remove the bad one and copy the good one over.

Comment: @melpomene, I'm running them both the exact same way (in fact, the only way to run them in Materials Studio). While it does say `-e`, they're definitely files. I'm not executing them differently at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, that may be the case... How would I check for the presence of such characters?

Comment: @Martensite: use tools like `cmp` (on UNIX) to compare the files and not the copy+pasted data, convert the files to hex and compare this or similar. Details depend on your capabilities and the capabilities of your OS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I took a look using FC in the Windows terminal and it does seem like something's a little wonky between the two versions. That may have been the culprit. Thanks.

Comment: One thing is for sure... they are not identical...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steffen, check out also for ^M characters at the end of the line, often they cause problems in .txt files. did you save them in tab delimeited text or in windows formatted text, cause the latter doesn't add odd characters at the end.